# Linker can't find Lua library definition

Tags: c++, linux, lua, g++, linker-errors

So, I'm relatively new to C++ and I've been trying to run Lua files in my C++ project. To start off things, I ran this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Lua Console";

    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();

    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    return 0;
}
```

And the terminal command looks like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -L lib/liblua.a
```

Edit: Corrected to this

```
g++ main.cpp -Llib -llua
```

Lua libraries are installed on my system (Linux), but the linker can't find the definition for luaL_newstate(), despite the fact that I included the library in the command line:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `luaL_newstate()'
```

And that happens with any Lua function. I don't really know what went wrong, importing libraries in Linux was pretty straightforward up until now. This seems to be a problem with me not familiar with using libraries in my projects, but I couldn't find very useful documentation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So this problem has been solved, but still needs clarification; this issue happened because I built my Lua library as C and used it in C++. A trick sure is wrapping all of those headers with extern "C", however, Lua documentation suggests  you should simply use "#include <lua.hpp>", that header already contains the extern and is included in Lua library installation headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-L` option designates a folder where library files are kept; try `g++ main.cpp -Llib -llua`

Also wrap `#include` for Lua headers into `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
  #include <lualib.h>
  #include <lauxlib.h>
  #include <lua.h>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem seems to persist however.

Comment: You'll have to add -v option to see the detailed information about the exact linker command, so we can see what path is being provided. Can you copy lib/liblua.a to your local folder to see if it helps?

Comment: Tried that as well with no luck. Also tried to copy the .a library to /usr/lib. Console information looks as follows: https://pastebin.com/CHgkkSsi

Comment: Try wrapping #include for Lua headers into `extern "C"`:
`extern "C" {
    #include <lualib.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lua.h>
}`

Comment: I recommend to use `#include <lua.hpp>` instead of wrapping with `extern "C"`.